# ms access form to insert group of records

Tags: ms-access

I have a student database contains the following tables:

Student Table (Id, StudentName, ClassNum, ....)

Action Table (Id, ActionDate, studentID, Status, reason, note)

Status fields possible values are: attended(=1) absent(=2), permitted(=3).
I want to build a form has the two unbound fields (Class Number and date) in the top of the form. A subform should contain a grid (list) of all the students of that class number; each row of that grid consists of: Student name (non editable), status (drop-down list for example), reason (text box).
The form should show all the class students.

When the user enters data (status, reason and notes) the form should create a record in the action table with the student id, the date (entered in the top section) and the add data (i.e. status, reason made notes).

How can i build a form contains records from a table (with records not exist before adding them).

Comment: Fields cannot be 'unbound', controls can be 'unbound'.

Comment: Cross-posted http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=74207

Comment: You have already described the overall design and behavior of the form.  The final question seems to be asking for a complete tutorial of how Access forms and subforms work and how to implement the list of requirements.  This question is too broad for Stack Overflow.  Perhaps try the **Form Wizard** (on the Create ribbon) first.  I suggest searching the web for Access form tutorials, or if you have a local library, look for a good how-to Access book.  (And I don't not mean this to be snarky, rather this is exactly how I learned most of my programming knowledge. It's a great way to start.)

Comment: I know how to link teh main form to sub form. 
My problem, which i searched but could not find a solution, is:
What is the sub form source of records?
If I use  the Student table, then student table doesn't contain the required fields (status , reason and note)
If I use to the action table, then action table doesn't contain any row  related to that date and class number. Hence, the form will contain no rows.

Comment: The form needs to show all the student names (from student table filtered by class num: the unbound control at the top of the form), date (from the unbound field top of the from) , the rest of the fields will be null values (i.e status , reason and note) and filled bu the user.
The records in action table will not be created until the data is entered and saved. Hence.they will not be shown.

Comment: Welcome and a few hints for posting on Stack Overflow: 1) If you are the original poster (OP), it is best to edit and improve the actual question with details solicited in the comments.  Don't leave critical, clarifying details in the comments.  Take the time to rework the question to make it better.  Not only will you likely get more upvotes, but probably better answers also. 2) When replying to someone in comments, make sure to reference them using @ or they will not be actively notified.  For more details, click the help link to the right of the comment textbox.

Comment: I await an edited question clarifying on what to focus (still too many unknowns for one question IMO). In the mean time I would suggest... A) placing the unbound filter controls in the form header and/or visually separate them;

Comment: B) making the form **single purpose**.  As an Action form, present the students in a ListBox or ComboBox, filtered by the class number. *Don't have a subform for students.*  This will allow you to definitely select a student. You could have critical but minimal details presented for the selected student, but don't make this form a place to edit or view all student details; C) having the editable action list in a subform, linked to the main form by the selected student (e.g. in ListBox).  Set the default action date for new records from the main form filter date.

Comment: *Disclaimer*: Multiple form designs are possible, hence my comment that the question is too broad. My suggestions are for designing a basic, functional form, but do not answer other requirements like whether past actions should be immediately editable in the subform?  Whether the unbound date should have a dual role as both a 1) default date for new actions AND 2) as a filter for the action subform,  or 3) only one of those. (Those distinct purposes can be naively combined which can effect the usefulness / bugginess of the form.), etc., etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need an INSERT SELECT action SQL to create a batch of records in Action table.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Action(StudentID, ActionDate) SELECT ID, " & _
"#" & Me.tbxDate & "# FROM Students WHERE ClassNum = " & Me.tbxClassNum
```

If ClassNumber is a text field, will need apostrophe delimiters for filter criteria.

This assumes each student can have only one class. If they can have multiple classes, then need ClassNumber field in Action.

Then filter form for that batch of records to do data entry to other fields in Action.